# lirc refusing to play

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I've installed lirc on a Raspberry Pi (running Wheezy) but can't get it to send any signal.

The LED is hooked up correctly (tested it using a python script).

See it working [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap5V37-9Fe0).

I used [this site](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote) to install lirc.

Here's the contents of `/etc/modules`:

```
snd-bcm2835
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=22
```

contents of `/etc/lirc/hardware.conf`

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"
LOAD_MODULES=true
DRIVER="default"
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

Contents of `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`

```
# brand:                       TV LG 42"LD420
# model no. of remote control: AKB72915207

begin remote

  name  LG
  bits           16
  flags SPACE_ENC|CONST_LENGTH
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       9056  4448
  one           601  1647
  zero          601   538
  ptrail        601
  repeat       9081  2199
  pre_data_bits   16
  pre_data       0x20DF
  gap          108229
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0

      begin codes
          KEY_POWER                0x10EF                    #  Was: power
          energy                   0xA956
          avmode                   0x0CF3
          input                    0xD02F
          tvrad                    0x0FF0
          KEY_1                    0x8877                    #  Was: 1
          KEY_2                    0x48B7                    #  Was: 2
          KEY_3                    0xC837                    #  Was: 3
          KEY_4                    0x28D7                    #  Was: 4
          KEY_5                    0xA857                    #  Was: 5
          KEY_6                    0x6897                    #  Was: 6
          KEY_7                    0xE817                    #  Was: 7
          KEY_8                    0x18E7                    #  Was: 8
          KEY_9                    0x9867                    #  Was: 9
          KEY_0                    0x08F7                    #  Was: 0
          KEY_LIST                 0xCA35                    #  Was: list
          q.view                   0x58A7
          KEY_VOLUMEUP             0x40BF                    #  Was: vol_up
          KEY_VOLUMEDOWN           0xC03F                    #  Was: vol_down
          KEY_CHANNELUP            0x00FF                    #  Was: ch_up
          KEY_CHANNELDOWN          0x807F                    #  Was: ch_down
          KEY_FAVORITES            0x7887                    #  Was: fav
          ratio                    0x9E61
          KEY_MUTE                 0x906F                    #  Was: mute
          KEY_MENU                 0xC23D                    #  Was: menu
          KEY_INFO                 0xD52A                    #  Was: guide
          q.menu                   0xA25D
          KEY_UP                   0x02FD                    #  Was: up
          KEY_DOWN                 0x827D                    #  Was: down
          KEY_LEFT                 0xE01F                    #  Was: left
          KEY_RIGHT                0x609F                    #  Was: right
          KEY_OK                   0x22DD                    #  Was: ok
          KEY_BACK                 0x14EB                    #  Was: back
          KEY_INFO                 0x55AA                    #  Was: info
          KEY_EXIT                 0xDA25                    #  Was: exit
          KEY_RED                  0x4EB1                    #  Was: red
          KEY_GREEN                0x8E71                    #  Was: green
          ellow                    0xC639
          KEY_BLUE                 0x8679                    #  Was: blue
          KEY_BLUE                 0x8679                    #  Was: blue
          exit2                    0x04FB
          t.opt                    0x847B
          KEY_SUBTITLE             0x9C63                    #  Was: subtitle
          KEY_STOP                 0x8D72                    #  Was: stop
          KEY_PLAY                 0x0DF2                    #  Was: play
          KEY_PAUSE                0x5DA2                    #  Was: pause
          KEY_REWIND               0xF10E                    #  Was: <<
          KEY_FORWARD              0x718E                    #  Was: >>
          simplink                 0x7E81
      end codes

end remote
```

I then created a script to fire off the power botton (`KEY_POWER`) a few times:

```
#! /bin/bash

powerkey(){
counter=0
        while [ $counter -lt 15 ]; do
                echo $counter
                irsend SEND_ONCE LG KEY_POWER
                sleep 0.1
                let counter=counter+1
        done
}

powerkey

exit 0
```

The numbers echo to the console but the IRLED doesn't light up.
I've also tried running the irsend SEND_START LG KEY_POWER - same result

I've also tested this outside of a bash script, just in the console, and still the IRLED just stays dark.

Here's the results of `ls -l /dev/ | grep lirc`

```
crw-rw---T 1 root video   244,   0 Jan  1  1970 lirc0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          21 Sep 30 00:00 lircd -> ../var/run/lirc/lircd
```

Any Ideas?

P.S. I'm asking this in `unix.` becuase it is **L**inux **I**nfrared **R**emote **C**ontrol

Comment: Those pulses are measured in microseconds - if you want to *see* them (assuming the infra-red LED is even capable of emitting visible light), you'd have to increase the values for `one` and `zero` to something much larger.

Comment: Hey @JigglyNaga, Thanks for the input. I'm using a cellphone camera which is capable of displaying the IR (have a look at the Youtube link I put in the question). With lirc, it gives you the option to have a continuous send mode (`START_SEND`) instead of a single "`SEND_ONCE`". My camera is capable of reading the signal from the actual remote, so, the very same signal should be sent from lirc as well. (meaning I should be able to see it).